# Webpage: Display python code from another program

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi, camera

I have a question if something that I am trying is generally possible.

```
@app.route('/live' , methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def live():
  import livestreamcamera      <--- this is what i want (java file, code executed on webpage)
  output = livestreamcamera
  return output
```

I run a Webpage in Flask (on my R Pi 5) in which I am able to record, livestream, play and delete videos. Although there is a problem in which when the livestream is still ongoing whilst recording, that opencv uses the same frames for recording (meaning the livestream lags and the recording lags). When I turn of the livestream the recording is fine. So I built a redirect to http://myip:port/live where i want to try to display the livestream seperately from another program. I could not get opencv running fluently when two methods share the same camera (threading also does not work)

Is what I am trying generally possible? I already tried setting up the program with another port but I would like to keep it on the same one.
Thanks!

Comment: related question, same author: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78101954/multiple-initializations-of-cv2-videocapture

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer myself:

you need to directly address the method in another file that has been called:

livestream file:

```
def test():
    output = "test"
    return output
```

The file where you want to import another:

```
@app.route('/live' , methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def live():
  import livestreamcamera
  output = livestreamcamera.test()
  return output
```

This may fix the syntax, but not the problem itself, as OpenCV cannot have multiple initializations of the same camera, even in another method