# multiple initializations of CV2 VideoCapture

Tags: python, opencv, flask, camera

**I need to use the camera while it is already recording** --> for video streaming at the same time

I heard that it is not possible to call multiple initializations of

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Thats why I called another python program in which it calls the method too but it still wont work.

> [ WARN:4@7.428] global cap_v4l.cpp:997 open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by
> index
> [ERROR:4@7.429] global obsensor_uvc_stream_channel.cpp:159 getStreamChannelGroup Camera index
> out of range

I really need to have multiple initializations for my use case and do not want to change everything entirely. Any solutions? (**Threading** does not work, **imageio** also says that the device is busy)
If multiple initializations are not possible i will try to video stream directly from the frame recorded but that will be really clumsy

Comment: Why don't you capture once and then split tasks in parallel?

Comment: Evaluate? I dont quite understand

Comment: I think what @TinoD means is that isntead of having multiple leasners, have a single lister, and that lister will be able to grant the nececery captcher by request (maybe a request queue?). This prevent multiple access to the driver while granting you multiple points of entry. (presonly i sugggest using queue with callback function). 
How will it look:
A single listner that leasns to the video captcher
A queue to access the captcher functionality that can be called by multiple places/threads.
A publisher concumer pattern,

Comment: You cannot open a video capture in parallel, the device is already busy. Why don't you capture once, and from the capture divide your tasks in parallel? @KevinKeller

Comment: Does not quite meet my usecase, does not work for me

Comment: Already tried something similar, performance was horrible on both the recording and video stream.

Comment: So first things first, please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50911603/16815358 @KevinKeller

Comment: Second, please adjust your question to include the code that you already tried. Currently, you do not have a MRE in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the link havent seen this yet. Yes I was asking if there is a quick fix available but does not seem like it, so I will go for either this multithreadding approach or reading from the written

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257065/discussion-between-tino-d-and-kevin-keller).

Comment: related question, same author: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78101410/webpage-display-python-code-from-another-program

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not having multiple initializations of the camera but rather to share the frames between the recording and the video stream. One needs to look at how much frames the camera generally works in order to balance it better.

Declare e.g.:

```
FPS = 1/40
FPSSTREAM = 1/20
```

recording method:

```
....while(int(time.time() - start_time) < capture_duration ):
    ret, frame = video.read()
    if ret==True:
        out.write(frame)
        time.sleep(FPS)    <---------
    else: .....
```

Video stream method:

```
def video_stream():
while camera_on:
    ret, frame = video.read()
    if not ret:
        print("will adjust video stream speed, slight stuttering might occur")
        time.sleep(ADJUST)  <---- ignore this 
    else:
        ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpeg',frame)
        frame = buffer.tobytes()
        yield (b' --frame\r\n' b'Content-type: imgae/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame +b'\r\n')
        time.sleep(FPSSTREAM)   <--- here
```

if it is still lagging then adjust

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter(result,fourcc,15.0, (640,480)) <--
```

Adjust the framerate, for some reason, 15.0 works for me perfectly

If it is still lagging for some reason, try multiprocessing:

```
capture_process = mp.Process(target=recording, args=())
capture_process.start()
```